# Consulta no banco de dados retorna dado incorreto

Tags: java

Olá!
Estou fazendo uma consulta no banco de dados e ele esta retornando os dados incorretos (conforme mostra a imagem).
Ele esta retornando o caminho da classe dentro do pacote.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue abaixo o código da classe (para quem quiser ir exatamente onde faz a consulta, e lá para o final, na função "sqlPesquisarCargos").

```
package sistema.telas;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.lang.System.Logger;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

// import com.mysql.cj.x.protobuf.MysqlxNotice.Warning.Level;

import sistema.BancoDeDados;
import sistema.entidades.Cargo;

public class CargosConsultar extends JPanel{

    Cargo cargoAtual;
    JLabel labelTitulo, labelCargo;
    JTextField campoCargo;
    JButton botaoPesquisar, botaoEditar, botaoExcluir;
    DefaultListModel<Cargo> listasCargosModelo = new DefaultListModel();
    JList<Cargo> listaCargos;

    public CargosConsultar()
    {
        criarComponentes();
        criarEventos();
    }

    public void criarComponentes()
    {
        setLayout(null);

        labelTitulo = new JLabel("Consulta de cargos", JLabel.CENTER);
        labelTitulo.setFont(new Font(labelTitulo.getFont().getName(), Font.PLAIN, 20));     
        labelCargo = new JLabel("Nome do Cargo", JLabel.LEFT);

        campoCargo = new JTextField();

        botaoPesquisar = new JButton("Pesquisar Cargo");
        botaoEditar = new JButton("Editar Cargo");
        botaoEditar.setEnabled(false);
        botaoExcluir = new JButton("Excluir Cargo");
        botaoExcluir.setEnabled(false);

        listasCargosModelo = new DefaultListModel();

        listaCargos = new JList();
        listaCargos.setModel(listasCargosModelo);
        listaCargos.setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

        // setBounds(x, y, width, height);
        labelTitulo.setBounds(200, 20, 400, 50);
        labelCargo.setBounds(150, 120, 400, 20);
        campoCargo.setBounds(150, 140, 400, 40);
        botaoPesquisar.setBounds(560, 140, 130, 40);
        listaCargos.setBounds(150, 200, 400, 240);
        botaoEditar.setBounds(560, 360, 130, 40);
        botaoExcluir.setBounds(560, 400, 130, 40);

        add(labelTitulo);
        add(labelCargo);
        add(campoCargo);
        add(botaoPesquisar);
        add(listaCargos);
        add(botaoEditar);
        add(botaoExcluir);

        setVisible(true);

    }

    public void criarEventos()
    {

        botaoPesquisar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                sqlPesquisarCargos(campoCargo.getText());
            }

        });

        botaoExcluir.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // sqlDeletarCargo();
            }

        });

        listaCargos.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                cargoAtual = listaCargos.getSelectedValue();

                if(cargoAtual == null) {
                    botaoEditar.setEnabled(false);
                    botaoExcluir.setEnabled(false);
                }else {
                    botaoEditar.setEnabled(true);
                    botaoExcluir.setEnabled(false);                 
                }
            }

        });

    }

    private void sqlPesquisarCargos(String nome)
    {
        Connection conexao;
        Statement instrucaoSQL;
        ResultSet resultados;

        try {

            try {
                Class.forName(BancoDeDados.JDBC_DRIVER);
            }catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Erro: "+e.getMessage());
            }

            conexao = DriverManager.getConnection(BancoDeDados.stringDeConexao, BancoDeDados.usuario, BancoDeDados.senha);

            instrucaoSQL = conexao.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

            // resultados = instrucaoSQL.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM cargos");
            resultados = instrucaoSQL.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM cargos WHERE nome_ca LIKE '%"+nome+"%'");

            listasCargosModelo.clear();

            while(resultados.next())
            {
                Cargo cargo = new Cargo();
                cargo.setId(resultados.getInt("id_ca"));
                cargo.setNome(resultados.getString("nome_ca"));             
                listasCargosModelo.addElement(cargo);           
            }

        }catch(SQLException ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao realizar consulta, verifique o log de erros!");
            System.out.println("Erro: "+ex.getMessage());           
            // Logger.getLogger(CargosConsultar.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os dados do banco provavelmente estão sendo retornados corretamente, apenas devem estar sendo apresentados de maneira incorreta na tela.

Sobrescreva o `toString` da sua classe `Cargo` para expressar o valor desejado:

```
public class Cargo {
...

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return nome;
    }
}
```

Então o `nome` será apresentado na sua tela.

O método `toString` tem por objetivo retornar uma representação do objeto em `String`, e pode ser customizado de acordo. Várias implementações chamam esse método.

Verifique a documentação [aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString())

O ideal para esses problemas é você debugar e verificar onde está o problema de fato.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Nunca teria solucionado sem sua ajuda, obrigado!